# Gatling scala: Check that the status code belongs to a list

Tags: scala, gatling

For a scenario I want to check that status code of the response belongs to 200-209 or 304 or 404.

I tried the following but apparently it's not supported. And I can't find my use case in the [docs](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/check/).

```scala
scenario("Scenario example").exec(httpRequest
    .check(status.in(200 to 209, 304, 404)))
```

Is there a better solution other than listing the codes manually?

```scala
    .check(status.in(200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 304, 404))
```

Answer (score -1):

```scala
.check(
    status.in((200 to 209) ++ List(304, 404))
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

You passed something mixed with `Seq` and `Int`.

The method `in` takes `Seq[Int]`:

```scala
.check(
      status.in((201 to 209) :+ 303 :+ 304)
    )
```